# UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum at iphone development

Tags: iphone, video

The following error occurs, when i use the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (iphone) function in debug console.

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/VCH263.videodecoder" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/H264H2.videodecoder" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH2.videodecoder" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2 (7D11)/Symbols/System/Library/VideoDecoders/Slim.videodecoder" (file not found).
```

How can i fix this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem you have to fix, just a note that these particular libraries don't have symbols.

This won't affect your users or your program's operation.  Apple may fix it at some point, but you can't.

Comment: but the video isnt copied to the library. I got an error. sidenote: the preview jpg for the photo library is switched but the video isnt in the library. i got back a null error